# PHP - How to toggle a change on click of submit button?

Tags: php, html, toggle

Any ideas why the code below does not give current value of statement after submit button is pressed?

php:

```
if(isset($_POST["switch"])) {
    if($nm === "off"){
        $nm = "on";
    }
    else{
        $nm = "off";
    }
}
```

html:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" value="[ -= toggle =- ] <?php echo $nm;?>" id="tt" name="switch">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
    $nm = "off";
if(isset($_POST["switch"])) {
    if($nm == "off"){
        $nm = "on";
    }
    if($nm == "on"){
        $nm = "off";
    }
}
```

remove all that, and change it to:

```
$nm = isset($_POST["switch"]) ? "on" : "off";
```

Because you are simply checking what $nm is set to currently, and you set it to "off" in the beginning, it will always be OFF in your secondary if statement...

Comment: how is this different from original function? since when i press submit button the value will be still "on" and never switches back to "off" state?